# Ajuda com $this e self em php

Tags: php, static

```
abstract class BaseModel {
    public function find($params){
        $table = $this->$table;

        //...
    }
}

class User extends BaseModel {
    protected $table = "users";
}
```

se eu fizer:

```
$u = new User();
$u->find([]);
```

funciona nomalmente porque eu criei uma nova instancia da classe user.
mas se eu quiser fizer diretamente:

`User::find([]);`

eu não conssigo porque não a nenhuma referencia para o `$this`

como que eu resolvo isso?

Comment: Não entendi qual o problema a ser resolvido. É só não fazer o que não pode, Ou parar de usar OOP só porque está na moda. Afinal me parece que o que está tentando fazer é usar OOP onde não precisa, por isso está criando um problema. Mas sem maiores informações não posso garantir.

Comment: Mais fácil você explicar qual resultado quer obter, do que só mostrar a maneira que está tentando fazer. Se puder, clique em [edit] e explique melhor qual é o comportamento que o código deve ter. Aproveite e revise aquele `$protected` lá, que está um pouco "esquisito".

Comment: oque eu quero é poder usar a função find() como static, mas eu tambem quero poder instanciar a classe e usar o função find() normalmente.

Comment: Repetir o que você já disse na pergunta não acrescenta nada. Pra quê o `find` precisaria do `$this`? Essa e outras informações básicas tem que estar no corpo da pergunta, senão não dá pra saber o que você está tentando fazer, e nem se o resto do código está certo. Sugiro antes de mais nada dar uma lida em [Ask], e depois [edit] a pergunta com as informações relevantes.

Comment: Pra ficar mais claro é algo parecido com o laravel, tipo: na laravel eu posso fazer App\User::find(1); sem precisar instanciar uma classe App\User, da mesma forma que eu posso primeiro instanciar um obj App\User e depois usar o find ( $user->find(1) )

Comment: Entendi, a pessoa precisa mexer com laravel pra entender o que você está dizendo. Com certeza se `App\User::find(1)` funciona no laravel, a resposta é bem simples: o laravel não usa o `$this` no find. Aliás, nem faria sentido. Se precisar de `$this` num método estático, você já tem erro em outras partes do código.

Comment: Cada vez mais confirma o que eu disse inicialmente está tentando pegar algo que não é OOP e tentar fazer virar OOP à força. Não vai funcionar mesmo.

Comment: ja resolvi meu problema, os caras do tableless consseguiram me entender e me ajudaram em 2 min. sem complicação. obg pela atenção de vcs

Comment: Que bom que resolveu.Se quiser postar a solução aqui pra ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema, pode publicar como resposta, faz parte das regras do site. E, desde que seja uma solução boa, que responda o que está na pergunta, e ensine certo as pessoas, pode receber votos positivos.

Answer (score 2):

Pode resolver isso simplesmente mantendo da forma como já está fazendo

```
$u = new User();
$u->find([]);
```

O `$this` não pode ser acessado estaticamente. Por isso não funcionará fazer `User::find([]);`

É possível fazer o que pretende, mas não recomendado.

Se o intuito for meramente visual, para ter um código menor, esqueça isso. Ou se o intuito for prover um acesso `inline`, pode pensar em outra forma como **[method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125268/chaining-static-methods-in-php)** ou simplesmente criar uma função:

```
function userFinD()
{
    $u = new User();
    return $u->find([]);
}

userFinD();
```

Mas se ficar incomodado em ter que criar uma função, também pode invocar inline uma rotina com múltiplas linhas. Para isso usa-se [funções anônimas](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Como não sei ao certo o que realmente pretende fazer, evitarei detalhar sobre as opções citadas.

Comment: obg pela sua ajuda, mas eu decide usar outro metodo para esse meu proposito. ficou até melhor. de qualquer forma obgd!

Answer (score -2):

SOLUÇÂO:

```
abstract class BaseModel {
    public function find($params){
        $table = '';

        if($this)
            $table = $this->$table;
        else {
            $u = new User();
            $table = $u->table;
            unset($u);
        }

        //...
    }
}

class User extends BaseModel {
    protected $table = "users";
}
```

Comment: Não entendi onde isso soluciona o que foi perguntado.